# Scala 2.13 error: type mismatch found Iterable[String,Double] required: java.util.Map[String,Double]

Tags: scala, type-conversion

I have a scala project that I need to migrate from scala 2.12 to 2.13. I have a simple code that converts a scala Map to a Java.util.Map. I am using the asJava method to do so, the code is simple

```scala
val jMap : java.util.Map[String,java.lang.Double]= imputerMap.mapValues(Double.box).asJava
```

but I get an error

```
found   : Iterable[(String, Double)]
[ERROR]  required: java.util.Map[String,Double]
[ERROR]     val jMap : java.util.Map[String,java.lang.Double]= imputerMap.mapValues(Double.box).asJava
```

At the documentation of `scala 2.13` I see that the imported changed to
`import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._`
but I dont see that it should break
How can I do the conversion now?

Answer (score 2):

As you already saw, the convertions between scala and java collections have changed from scala 2.12 to scala 2.13:

- [CONVERSIONS BETWEEN JAVA AND SCALA COLLECTIONS](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html) (scala **2.8** - **2.12**)

> To enable these conversions, simply import them from the [JavaConverters](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.18/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html) object:
>
> ```scala
> import collection.JavaConverters._
> ```

- [CONVERSIONS BETWEEN JAVA AND SCALA COLLECTIONS](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html) (scala **2.13**)

> To enable these conversions, import them from the [CollectionConverters](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.11/scala/jdk/CollectionConverters$.html) object:
>
> ```scala
> import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._
> ```

---

Also the signature of the method `mapValues` from `Map` class changed:

- [mapValues - scala 2.12](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.18/scala/collection/MapLike.html#mapValues%5BW%5D(f:V=%3EW):scala.collection.Map%5BK,W%5D)

```scala
  /** Transforms this map by applying a function to every retrieved value.
   *  @param  f   the function used to transform values of this map.
   *  @return a map view which maps every key of this map
   *          to `f(this(key))`. The resulting map wraps the original map without copying any elements.
   */
  override def mapValues[W](f: V => W): Map[K, W]
```

- [mapValues - scala 2.13](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/Map.html#mapValues%5BW%5D(f:V=%3EW):scala.collection.MapView%5BK,W%5D) (deprecated since scala 2.13)

```scala
  /** Transforms this map by applying a function to every retrieved value.
    *  @param  f   the function used to transform values of this map.
    *  @return a map view which maps every key of this map
    *          to `f(this(key))`. The resulting map wraps the original map without copying any elements.
    */
  @deprecated("Use .view.mapValues(f). A future version will include a strict version of this method (for now, .view.mapValues(f).toMap).", "2.13.0")
  def mapValues[W](f: V => W): MapView[K, W]
```

`mapValues` returns a `MapView`. You can find info about views in the following links

- [Views in Scala 2.12](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/views.html)
- [Views in Scala 2.13](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/views.html)

> To go **from** a **collection** **to** its **view**, you can **use** the **view method** on the collection. If `xs` is some **collection**, then `xs.view` is the **same collection**, but with all **transformers implemented lazily**. To get back **from** a **view** **to** a **strict collection**, you can use the to conversion operation with a strict collection factory as parameter (e.g. `xs.view.to(List)`)

So, your code should be refactored as

```scala
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

val jMap: java.util.Map[String, java.lang.Double] = 
  imputerMap
    .view // use view as the deprecated method suggeted
    .mapValues(Double.box)
    .to(Map) // transform from lazy collection to strict one
    .asJava  // the method to convert to java collection
```